# Valid to hash bytes using XOR shift?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, xor

Is it valid to XOR shift bytes to produce a hash/checksum?  I can't find any evidence that it collides more than say CRC32.

This code seems to run about 40x faster than Java's util.zip.CRC32 class.

```
public static long hash64( byte[] bytes )
    {
    long x = 1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ )
        {
        x ^= bytes[ i ];
        x ^= ( x << 21 );
        x ^= ( x >>> 35 );
        x ^= ( x << 4 );
        }

    return x;
    }


public static int hash32( byte[] bytes )
    {
    int x = 1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ )
        {
        x ^= bytes[ i ];
        x ^= ( x << 13 );
        x ^= ( x >>> 17 );
        x ^= ( x << 5 );
        }

    return x;
    }
```

Comment: Apart from the close reason, another reason this is off-topic is because you're not even trying to build a collision resistant hash in the cryptographic sense.

Comment: I am sure you are right.  Although I did run a simulation on 10million randomly generated 8-32 byte arrays and the hash32 method actually produced 2% less collisions than CRC32.

Comment: @OnesAndZeroes: your test with random input does not demonstrate collision resistance in a cryptographic sense. In cryptography, the adversary is expected to use crafted (rather than random) input if that fits her/his objective. Collisions for MD5 are commonly found, but not among random input.

Comment: Understood.  This isn't for security.  It's just for a network checksum.  I've reposted to a more appropriate site.